# Where do these boot problems come from?

Tags: 12.04, boot, usb

Sometimes, the login-screen doesn't appear at boot but this message:

```
cannot set freq 16000 to ep 0x86
cannot set freq 24000 to ep 0x86
cannot set freq 32000 to ep 0x86
cannot set freq 48000 to ep 0x86
```

After 1-2 reboots by long pressing the power-button it works normally. What's the problem?

This message first appeared after I plugged an USB 2.0 device to my USB 3.0 port before boot. But now it even says that with no device plugged on an USB 3.0 port

Edit: Now there's a new problem: sometimes I can only start into tty! I think it also has to do with the problem above